# Enabling TTL (Time-to-Live) On ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I am adding documents once per second to an ElasticSearch whose TTL is disabled.

Each document has a TTL of `2h`.

After one hour, I enable TTL on the index.

I continue adding documents up until the beginning of the second hour.

In my mind, the chain of events which should occur is:

```
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
|     |     |           |
|     |     |           |_4hr: All documents dead
|     |     |_2hr: Stop adding documents, first documents should die
|     |_1hr: Enable TTL on index
|_0hr: Begin adding documents
```

This corresponds to the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), but is it actually what happens? The [TTL documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html) doesn't explain what happens if an index's TTL is turned on late, or on and off repeatedly.

Naturally, answers making use of references to solid documentation are most appreciated.